# How do bitcoin miners collect coin?

Tags: mining-theory, mining-hardware, mining-reward

I was wondering how miners claim the reward? They find the nonce and then do they send that value to a Bitcoin server endpoint where it's validated? I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel but I don't understand how data gets from equipment in the mining farm to become part of the ledger. Forgive me if any part of that doesn't make sense. I'm new here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reward system bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36647/reward-system-bitcoin)

Comment: If not, maybe one of these: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/101905/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/112467/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/111388/5406