# Who/What generates Bitcoin Hashes to be mined?

Tags: mining-theory

**Bitcoin miners decrypt hashes, but who or what encrypts them in the first place?** After all, something must have encrypted it so that miners could find it.

Comment: I think you might be interested in reading this question:
http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8031/what-are-bitcoin-miners-really-solving/8033#8033

Answer (score 1):

"Decrypting hashes" is not really a correct way to describe the calculation, and nobody "encrypts" them, which is probably why you could find no information on this notion.

The hashes that miners calculate are based on all the transactions on the network, metadata and previous block hashes.

Comment: How is hash generated?

Comment: @l0oky: See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Block_Headers. The miner simply takes all the data in the block header and hashes it, each time with a different nonce. When the nonces are exhausted, extraNonce is incremented which changes the Merkle Root.