# Where can I find the structure and layout of what exactly gets hashed by miners?

Tags: blockchain, mining-technical-details

I understand that a miner has a list of bitcoin transactions since the last time a a block was discovered. The first entry is the reward for who discovered the previous block. As more transactions gets added, they're appended to this list. This part is speculation, but I think there's also a nonce that the miners inject in order to produce a hash output that meets the difficulty.

Where can I find out the specifics about what exactly is hashed? I'm looking to understand the exact bytes and structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are bitcoin miners really solving?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/8031/5406)

Comment: The first entry is _not_ the reward for who discovered the previous block. The first transaction is unique to each miner and causes the block reward of the *upcoming* block to be spend to the miner that discovers the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that's hashed is the *block header*. You can find a description of the format and layout at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm

Comment: How does a Generation block differ? What goes in the `hashPrevBlock` section of the generation block? All zeros?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: Do you mean the [genesis block](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Genesis_block), the very first block in the block chain?  Yes, the `hashPrevBlock` field is set to zero.  Everything else is the same.